# Google action required: Violation of User Data policy

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

We recently got a mail from Google saying that there is a User Data Policy violation.

The mail says:

> We reviewed SDKs used by your app and found noncompliant version(s) of SDK(s) which collects persistent device identifiers. Persistent device identifiers may not be linked to other personal and sensitive user data or resettable device identifiers.
>
> Your app may face additional enforcement actions, if you do not resolve this issue by February 28, 2024 .
>
> Issue details
>
> We found an issue in the following area(s):
> Version code 1101
> -> SDK: Fabric (Firebase Crashlytics)- ID Bridging io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric(consider upgrading version com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0)

The problem is that the issue was found in the latest version, which is already uploaded to Closed Beta and Production tracks (100%).
And since I am literally got in all of this like 1 month ago and the person responsible for this happened to quit like 2 years ago I have no idea what to do and who to ask.

Also, where can I check the data or information collected by Fabric SDK? We have TwitterLib folder, but I have not a slightest idea what this is as well and what else to try.

Our programmers say that the problem may be solved by deleting the Fabric SDK and upload the new version again.

Does anybody else has this problem? How did you solve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What happened with you followed this advice - *consider upgrading version com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0*? (although I believe the current version is 18.6)

Comment: @Jay Programmers that are working on this one currently decided to delete/clear the Fabric SDK, but after they did that, they asked me if there will be any issues if they do the build without it, because once it is not in the build the problem should be solved (that's what they have told me) and I have no idea if it will affect the app or not.

Comment: Seems like our developers have resolved the issue just now by simply deleting the Fabric SDK as there is no need for crashlytics for that app now. 
Thank you for your attention and time! :)